# Always allow microphone usage in Google Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, microphone

Is there a way to always allow Google Chrome to use my microphone and camera for a certain site?  I like using the new Google Voice Search but whenever I click the mic button it asks if Chrome is allowed to use my mic, how can I set it to always allow?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way. It's a security thing.

Answer (score 6):

If you are connected to the site via HTTS the grant is permanent, if you use HTTP, you are asked each time.

Probably it is a security measure to prevent users who spoof the URL of a website you have previously authorized to use the camera.

But it sucks.

Answer (score 1):

- Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
- Select *Settings*.
- Click *Show advanced settings*.
- In the *Privacy* section, click *Content settings*.
- Under *Media*, Click *Manage exceptions* to remove previously-granted permissions for specific sites.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, when you click Allow, it will add it to a safe list of sites. In order to save the to the safe list, you must be logged into your google account.

I thought I was logged in, but I actually wasnt logged into the browser. Log into the browser and click allow and it will save Google in the safe list for the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is not certain, google is using a lock for some distros, and you cant enable the search engine with the mic with google voice, the browser will take this like a non authorized action.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Your answer is difficult to understand. Could you rewrite it using complete and elaborating sentences? It would improve your answer greatly.